# AKS cluster pods kube config location

Tags: c#, kubernetes, kubectl, azure-aks

I am trying to perform some operations on my AKS cluster using a C# worker service that is using the [kubernetes client library](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/csharp). Currently my service is running on a single pod in the cluster. When I try to perform the `CreateSecret` operation , I get a **403 exception**.

I tried getting a bearer token and used that to set the KubeConfig's AccessToken but that also does not work.

I am wondering if there is a way I can access the kubeconfig from my pod (which I guess is only available on the master node?) or is there a different location of config which I can point to?

Comment: HTTP error 403 is Forbidden.  Usually means you do not have access rights to the data or your authentication is wrong (token may be wrong).Normally I recommend use the vendors tools first before developing at c# application. If you get the vendor tool working then use a sniffer like wireshark or fiddler and compare the headers in the working tool with the c# headers.  Make the c# look like vendor headers.  The default header in c# are different from other apps.  TLS is often used for authentication and in June TLS 1.0/1,1 was obsoleted and you must use 1.2.  You must use APIs that support 1.2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest to use service account instead of `kubeconfg` since you are running the application inside the cluster as pod.

```
var config = KubernetesClientConfiguration.InClusterConfig()
```

Above code will use the `default` service account in the namespace where the pod is deployed. You will get a `Forbidden` error and to solve that you need to define [RBAC](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/rbac/) to provide authorization to the service account. Below is the `Role` and `RoleBinding` assuming you are using `default` namespace for deploying the pod.

```
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: Role
metadata:
  namespace: default
  name: secret-creator
rules:
- apiGroups: [""]
  resources: ["secrets"]
  verbs: ["create"]
---
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: RoleBinding
metadata:
  name: role-binding
roleRef:
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: Role
  name: secret-creator
subjects:
- kind: ServiceAccount
  name: default
  namespace: default
```

Comment: I tried the above Role and RoleBinding, but I could still see this error from my KubeClient : 

`Error in KubeClient :{"kind":"Status","apiVersion":"v1","metadata":{},"status":"Failure","message":"secrets \"test\" is forbidden: User \"system:serviceaccount:default:default\" cannot get resource \"secrets\" in API group \"\" in the namespace \"istio-system\"","reason":"Forbidden","details":{"name":"test","kind":"secrets"},"code":403}`

And to add, I have to create the secret in the Istio-System namespace, and my service is running on a pod with default namespace.

Comment: Post reading about ClusterRole, I modified the above yaml to this : 

`apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRole
metadata:
  name: secret-creator
rules:
- apiGroups: [""]
  resources: ["secrets"]
  verbs: ["create"]
---
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRoleBinding
metadata:
  name: role-binding
roleRef:
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: ClusterRole
  name: secret-creator
subjects:
- kind: ServiceAccount
  name: default
  namespace: default`

But that also did not work.

Comment: Marking it accepted as the ClusterRole worked, just that in the verbs I added, list and delete as well, because I was using them too and they were still throwing 403. Thank you for the help @Arghya!